# Why can i assign a value to a rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue, lvalue

I recently started learning about rvalues,lvalues, move semantics and I can't understands some conceps like rvalue refs .. why can I assign a value to a rvalue ref like : `int&& x = 10;`.. doesn't that mean that an rvalue ref is an lvalue(I tought that a rvalue ref is a rvalue)? If that is true ... what's the point of having rvalue references? If that is false then what is the difference between an rvalue ref and an lvalue ?

Comment: This one is initialization, you initially bind the reference to a temporary thus prolonging that latter's lifetime.

Comment: Ohh i just tested somthing: If i have a function with a paramter ->rvalue ref... that functions takes only rvalues.. if i try to give it a simple variable it will give an error

Comment: @Robert Yes, that's a much better use case. You can even make two overloaded functions, one that takes an lvalue-ref and one that takes and r-value ref. Then it start being very useful, since you know when you can move and when you need to copy.

Comment: @Robert a variable alone is a lvalue regardless of its type. You'd need to `std::move` it explicitly. @rustyx cppreference.org is enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why can I assign a value to a rvalue ref like : int&& x = 10

That's not an assignment. That's initialisation. Here, a temporary object is materialised from the integer constant and the reference is bound to that temporary. Same thing can be done with lvalue references to const: `const int& x = 10`. It cannot be done with lvalue references to non-const since they cannot be bound to rvalues.

> doesn't that mean that an rvalue ref is an lvalue

Only expressions have values. `int&& x = 10;` is a declaration and not an expression. Thus the declaration doesn't have a value in the first place.

The declaration contains an expression `10` which is a prvalue.

Types are not expressions either, so "rvalue reference is an lvalue" is meaningless.

Variables don't have value categories either. However id-expressions - which are just expressions that name a variable - do have a value category. They are lvalues regardless of the type of the named variable - yes, even if the type is rvalue reference.

Comment: Very interesting. But then the question remains, "why can I initialize a rvalue with `int&& x = 10`?", i.e. what is the point of being able to do that, its utility? **Disclaimer**: I am also beginner in move semantics.

Comment: @roi_saumon It's not useful outside of templates. But within a template, lifetime extension of references is useful because we want to be able to treat references equally with reference wrappers that may be prvalues.

Comment: Would you happen to have a link with an example?